# Derivative of list of points: DifferentiatorFilter versus DerivativeFilter

Tags: numerics, finite-difference-method, function-comparison

I need to calculate the derivative from a list of experimental points. Mathematica has two functions which seem to do this: DifferentiatorFilter and DerivativeFilter. Which one is better for calculating a derivative? Is there one that implements a finite difference method?

From the documentation:

> DifferentiatorFilter is commonly used to approximate the derivative of
>   data. Data smoothing with cutoff frequency omega.

and

> DerivativeFilter is a linear filter that computes the derivatives of
>   data based on a spline interpolation model. Regularization with a
>   Gaussian kernel of standard deviation [Sigma] (default value is
>   [Sigma]=0) can be used to reduce susceptibility to noise.

thanks!

Comment: I'd try using `ListInterpolation` and then `Derivative`. Maybe it's what `DerivativeFilter` does?

Comment: I'd use both, and check each with different values of smoothing. Use the one that shows best what you wish to demonstrate. It's like the old proverb: a man with one watch knows what time it is; a man with two watches is never sure.

Comment: If the spacing is regular there are also `Fourier`-based approaches. But I'd try what others have suggested first in any case.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I've tried with my data, and both functions work ok. `DerivativeFilter` does multiple order derivatives and `DifferentiatorFilter` only does first derivatives, but otherwise both work.


bill-s: `DerivativeFilter` seems to be the same as `Derivative[ListInterpolation[]]`.